# Get results / report for a Selenium test suite within Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

When I launch a huge Selenium test suite on  Eclipse, I usually get a veeeery long list of ok / ko / error. Then, when I decide to play a single test case, the whole test suite result just disappears (which is quite normal).

The problem is I'm having a hard time saving these results in order to play again the test cases which failed. Actually -don't laugh- I take screenshots of my Eclipse view...

I'm sure there's a way to generate a lovely test suite report within Eclipse.

Any idea?

Comment: What testing library are you using. Junit?

Comment: Yes! Does it have any out of the box reporting solution for test suites? (For now we only generate log files for each individual test case)

Comment: No directly as far as I'm aware. However if you use a buildscript (eg. ant, maven) you can use this to generate reports.